Whatsapp Business Cloud API - Track messages
If I have wamid, is there a way to retrieve all message information, including whether it was sent, delivered, or read via the API?
I am receiving via webhook status sent, delivered and read, however, the wamid sent in the webhook is different from the message with text content
I need to update the status (sent, delivered and read) of the message with text content.
The first message with text content has a different wamid than the warning via webhook with the information sent, deliveres and read

Can you explain how you are receiving status of read/sent via webhook? I am also trying to receive read/deliered status. But the messages object only returns message_status as 'accepted' or 'held_for_quality_assessment' and I can't seem to find any other way with cloud API. Thanks for help!
